# linear trasnformation

Tags: linear-transformations

In Einstein's "The Meaning of Relativity" https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Relativity/Lecture_1 by putting $λ = 1$, (2b) and (3a) should furnish the conditions:

$ \sum \limits _{\nu }b_{\nu \alpha }b_{\nu \beta }=\delta _{\alpha \beta }$

but If I do myself the passages by replacing (3a) in (2b) I get:

$\sum_v (\sum_\alpha b_{\nu \alpha } \Delta x_{\alpha})^2 = \sum_\nu \Delta x_{\nu }^{2}$

so that the equality condition should be:

$b_{\nu\alpha} = \delta_{\nu\alpha}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The sum on $\alpha$ should be inside the square

Answer (score 1):

Plugging $\Delta x_\nu' = \sum_\alpha b_{\nu\alpha}\Delta x_\alpha$
into $\sum_\nu \Delta x_\nu'^2 = \sum_\nu \Delta x_\nu^2$ gives
$$\sum_\nu \left(\sum_\alpha b_{\nu\alpha}\Delta x_\alpha\right)^2 = \sum_\nu \Delta x_\nu^2$$
Note that the sum on $\alpha$ belongs inside the square. Now expand the square on the left side.

Added:

In general to expand something like this, you do:

$$(\sum_\alpha c_{\alpha})^2 = \sum_{\alpha,\beta} c_{\alpha}c_{\beta}$$

See if you can get it from there.

Comment: Can you show me, how to expand the left side?

Comment: @mattfick I added a suggestion, see if you can figure it out from there!